# Create excel workbooks from access rows

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Here is what I am trying to do. I am trying to create a workbook based on a template named by the title and to create a workbook for each row. And for the macro to loop until all rows have been depleted.

The deliverables that I want at the end are 3 excel documents named (Alpha.xlsx, Beta.xlsx, Gamma.xlsx) with the corresponding values from access plugged into their corresponding cells in their corresponding workbook. The subsequent math is there because I need to be able to manipulate the values once they are in excel.

Here is some of the research that I've found that I haven't quite been able to make much sense of due to my lack of experience coding in vba.

### Links

(I can't post more than 2 so I'll keep the number of articles terse):

**Research:** databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3563671/Export-Data-To-Excel.htm

**Example Database/Spreadsheet:** 
http://www.sendspace.com/file/iy62c0

**Image Album** (has a picture of the database and the template in case you don't want to download):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/75fvd.jpg

Any help will be much appreciated! I've been reading up and trying to figure out how to get this to work @.@

Comment: If there is anything that I can clarify please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: time to upgrade to mysql or sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't complete, but should help you get started...

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'Enter Location of your Template Here
Const ExcelTemplate = "C:\MyTemplate.xltx"
'Enter the Folder Directory to save results to
Const SaveResutsFldr = "C:\Results\"
Sub CreateWorkbook()
Dim SaveAsStr As String
Dim ExcelApp, WB As Object

'Create Reference to Run Excel
Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Create Reference to your Table
Dim T As Recordset
Set T = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblData")

'Loop through all Record on Table
While Not T.BOF And T.EOF
    'Open Your Excel Template
    Set WB = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelTemplate)

    'Enter your data from your table here to the required cells
    WB.Worksheets("NameOfYourWorkSheet").Range("A1") = T("numValue1")
    'Repeat this line for each piece of data you need entered
    'Changing the Sheet name, cell range, a field name as per your requirements
    'WB.Wor...
    'WB.Wor...

    'Save and Close the Workbook
    SaveAsStr = SaveResutsFldr & T("Title") & ".xlsx"
    WB.SaveAs SaveAsStr
    WB.Close
    Set WB = Nothing

    'Move to the Next Record
    T.MoveNext
Wend

'Close down the Excel Application
ExcelApp.Quit
Set ExcelApp = Nothing
End Sub
```